# Postgresql-8.4 auto vacuum is enabled to get the best performance

Tags: database, postgresql, vacuum

I want know which one is good to follow whether auto vacuum or vacuum manually. Right now we are following manually in cron jobs, but sometimes it gets struck to vaccum on particular tables. so we are thinking about the auto vacuum. does it give good performance to production server? please suggest. Lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Performance tuning is a difficult subject. Auto vacuum works in most cases very well. In certain cases however "manual" vacuum using cron might work better because for instance you know the database has nothing to do at night while during the day the vacuum might be to disruptive.

A good book on postgres performance and tuning is [PostgreSQL 9.0 High performance](http://www.packtpub.com/postgresql-90-high-performance/book)